# Can you still create a Chrome packaged app in the browser with manifest 2.0?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

All of the examples I've seen show apps launching in their own windows.  This may be great an all for chromebook/chrome os, but is there still an option to launch in a browser tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. Chrome Packaged Apps are not supposed to run inside a browser. You can, however, open URLs in a browser tab using `window.open`. But you won't have control of that tab after you issue the command.

If you need some sort of integration/control between your Chrome Packaged App and the browser, you can create an extension and make a communication pipe between the extension and the app - as long as both are running, using the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` API.

See [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/messaging) for a simple code that does exactly that (two apps and one extension exchanging messages directly, without any server component).

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.app.window.create` will create a new Window for an App.

If you want window manipulation, you should switch to chrome.tabs API and look for an extension instead of an App.

## Reference

- [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)
- [chrome.app.window](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app.window.html)

Comment: This wouldn't work. I'm looking to launch a packaged app in a tab not a window and i'm not talking about extensions.

Comment: @tinyfugu: I know you are not talking about extensions all i am trying to say it is not possible to do till date without tabs.api. It seems you misunderstood the background of chrome apps Like native apps, they don’t live within the browser. So, launching in a tab is an invalid assumption

Comment: You cannot use chrome.tabs in packaged apps, only in extensions. It will show an error: "'tabs' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, and this is a packaged app."

Comment: @tinyfugu: You completely got me wrong, if you want to use chrome.tabs you should completely switch to extensions and you can not launch an app in a tab is what i am trying to convey, let me know if i am still unclear